# Should a class definition be put in the global or local scope?

Tags: c++, class, oop, organization

fellow programmers. I've seen it a common practice to put the class definition inside the global scope in a source file, above the `main()` function I'm not worrying about the details of the class definition for now.

```
class Dog { ... };

int main() {
    Dog dog1;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Why should we do this? Is it a rule or just a common convention? Can we also put the class definition inside the `main()` function? What are the advantages/disadvantages for doing this?

Consider the following two lines of code:

```
class Dog { ... } dog1;
int dog1;
```

To me it seems that `class Dog { ... }` is just a data type just like `int` is.

If I am going to use objects of some class inside the `main()` function only, why not put the class definition inside the `main()` function also? Is this bad programming practice? Or is this something that only C programmers do with structs? What is the reason to put the class definition in the global scope?

```
int main() {
    class Dog { ... };

    Dog d1;
    ...
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Local classes are sometimes useful. But ordinarily it's desirable to separate things that can be separated. As Caesar once noted, divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the definition of `Dog` inside `main`, that definition is scoped just like other names.

That means a function outside `main` doesn't see that definition of `Dog`, so you can't define (for example) a function that takes a `Dog` as a parameter. So, this works:

```
class Dog {};

void foo(Dog const &d); // no problem

int main() { 
    Dog d;
    foo(d);
}
```

...but this doesn't:

```
void foo(Dog const &d);

int main() { 
    class Dog {} d;
    foo(d);
}
```

... and adding a forward declaration of `Dog` doesn't really work either.

Most types should be visible to essentially all the code, so they're typically defined outside any function.

A few types are intended only to be used by one other particular type, in which case they're typically defined inside that type:

```
class linked_list {
    class node {};
};
```

Now there's a type named `linked_list::node`, but you need the `linked_list` qualifier to find `node` (and, of course, `node` has to be public for anything outside `linked_list` to use it, whereas here it's shown as private).

Comment: That linked list example is a good one! Really makes sense why you would make a local class.

Comment: You're right, the function doesn't know what a `Dog` is in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

It's rare that a local class will be useful. Take your example: what can you do with the `Dog` object? You can't pass it to any other function. No other code can do anything with it. What's the point of encapsulating its data in an object that has such limited scope?

Would all the machinery of a class benefit something with such limited usage? Constructors, destructors, member functions, operator overloading, etc. Not really useful. Would you have `private` variables? Probably not. What's the point; there's nobody to hide them from.

Sometimes it's useful to create a local `struct`, particularly a [plain old data (POD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) structure. A PODs with only public variables and no member functions could be useful for quickly grouping a couple of related values. Even still, such usage is rare.